# how to get the height of keyboard in ionic4

Tags: ionic4

Input in an Ion-Footer to fixed on the bottom in Ionic4, and when I focus the input, the keyboard overlaps the input; so I hope the input can fixed above the keyboard when it was focused. And in ionic3, I can add an event listener to get the keyboard's height, here is my codes:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBvEn.png)

It works fine in ionic3, but it doesn't work in ionic4~ Please help me, thx~

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it the same way. You just need to change the event name.

```
// RxJS
fromEvent(window, 'keyboardWillShow')

// ES6
window.addEventListener('keyboardWillShow', () => {})
```

I recommend to use the RxJS approach since you can easily unsubscribe from it using takeUntil or .unsubscribe.